# Conflict between the different INCLUDED JavaScript files

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I include the [enhance.js](http://filamentgroup.github.com/EnhanceJS/enhance.js) plugin it makes a conflict with other jquery plugins, such as UI jquery plugins

I can't use the date picker functions for example .

what is the possible solution ?

Comment: Have you got any code or console out put to show? hard to tell what it could be otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

And/or you can use aliasing here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure it's the problem as the library he is trying to use doesn't try to overwrite $ nor jQuery.